# MySQL .NET Connector package

Tags: mysql, mono, rpm, opensuse

I have a few projects that use MySQL Connector for .NET, either directly or through NHibernate.

Very simple question: in order to avoid maintaining the `Mysql.Data.dll` assembly on every project and for keeping up-to-date with the upstream development, does anyone provide a maintained MySQL Connector for .NET/Mono package for openSUSE?

It would go through YaST just fine.

If "no one yet" is the answer, I'll simply do `gacutil -i Mysql.Data.dll` as root. But an RPM could be finer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Dec 2014 a connector RPM [exists](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mono%28MySql.Data%29), but not yet available in official Yast distribution repository. Maybe in a separate community repository...

Answer (score 0):

No one yet :-)
Al least http://software.opensuse.org/ doesn't list any packages for it, and that is usually very exhaustive.